# AngularJs: Binding a property of a scope object to a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, directive

I'm somewhat new to AngularJs, so forgive me if this is a newb question, but I've looked around a bit and haven't been able to figure this out.

I'm trying to send an attribute of an object into a directive and I'm not quite sure why this isn't working.

I've got a scope variable that's an object, something like:

```
$scope.player = {name:"", hitpoints:10};
```

In my HTML, I'm attempting to bind that to a directive:

```
<span accelerate target="player.hitpoints" increment="-1">Take Damage</span>
```

In my directive, I'm attempting to modify player.hitpoints like this:

```
scope[attrs.target] += attrs.increment;
```

When I trace it out, scope[attrs.target] is undefined, even though attrs.target is "player.hitpoints." When I use target="player", that traces out just fine but I don't want to have to manipulate the .hitpoints property explicitly in the directive.

Edit: I've made a jsfiddle to illustrate what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/csafo41x/

Comment: does your directive have an isolated scope? Could you please share the code of your directive?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to share scope between your controller and directive. Here is very good post by Dan Wahlin on scope sharing in Directive - http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/creating-custom-angularjs-directives-part-2-isolate-scope

There are 3 ways to do so

- @  Used to pass a string value into the directive
- =    Used to create a two-way binding to an object that is passed into the directive
- &    Allows an external function to be passed into the directive and invoked

Just a very basic example on how the above mentioned scope are to be used

```
angular.module('directivesModule').directive('myIsolatedScopeWithModel', function () {
    return {
        scope: {
            customer: '=' //Two-way data binding
        },
        template: '<ul><li ng-repeat="prop in customer">{{ prop }}</li></ul>'
    };
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. I've tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. I've provided a jsfiddle that shows what I'm trying to do, in case that helps any.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of things going on here:

**#1 - scope**

Once you define your isolated scope (along the lines of @Yasser's answer), then you don't need to deal with `attrs` - just use `scope.target`.

**#2 - template**

Something actually needs to handle the click event. In your fiddle there is just `<span class="btn"...>`. You need `ng-click` somewhere. In your case, you probably want the directive to handle the click. So modify the directive's template and define the click handler in the directive's scope:

```
...
template: "<button class='btn' ng-click='click()'>Button</button>",
link: function(scope, element, attrs)
{
   scope.click = function(){
      scope.target += parseInt(attrs.increment);
   }
}
...
```

**#3 - transclude**

Now, you need to get the contents of the directive to be the contents of the button within your directive's template. You can use `transclude` parameter with `ng-transclude` -  for location, for that. So, the template above is modified to something like the following:

```
...
template: "<button class='btn' ng-click='click()'><div ng-transclude</div></button>",
transclude: true,
...
```

Here's your modified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/csafo41x/7/)